# failed to deserialize ROS message: Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type std_srvs::srv::dds_::Empty_Response_

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am creating a ROS Service in Unity Simulator of type std_srvs/Empty.

I am able to call the service, service is doing the intended work.

But when I return the empty response, I get the following error:

```
The following exception was never retrieved: failed to deserialize ROS message: Fast CDR exception deserializing message of type std_srvs::srv::dds_::Empty_Response_., at /home/user/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/src/type_support_common.cpp:118
```

can anyone help me with what could be going wrong?